# Looking for a "Black-Scholes-esque" expression for $E[\max(V-K,Y)]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, finance

In [Hull (2008, p. 307)](http://raudys.com/kursas/Options,%20Futures%20and%20Other%20Derivatives%207th%20John%20Hull.pdf), the following equation is found (Eq. 13A.2):

$$E[\max(V-K,0)]=\int_{K}^{\infty} (V-K)g(V)\:dV$$

Where $g(V)$ is the PDF of $V$, $K$ is a constant, and both $V,K>0$.  He then goes on to show that if $V$ is lognormally distributed, then

$$E[\max(V-K,0)]=VN(d_1)-KN(d_2)$$

where $N(x)$ is the standard normal distribution, $d_1=\frac{\ln(V/K)}{w}+\frac{w}{2}$ and $d_2=d_1-w$, and $w$ is the standard deviation of $\ln(V)$.

(You might recognize this as being very similar to the Black-Scholes equation.)

I would like to find a similar expression for $$E[\max(V-K,Y)]$$

For three cases:

1) where $Y$ is a positive constant

2) where $Y$ is an positive independent random variable

3) where $Y$ is a positive random variable conditional upon $V$

In an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087107/how-to-express-e-maxx-y-as-an-integral), I was told that, generally speaking, for two positive independent random variables X and Y, with CDFs $F(x)$ and $G(y)$,
$$E[\max(X,Y)]=\int_0^{\infty}wF(w)g(w)dw+\int_0^{\infty}wf(w)G(w)dw$$

This was informative but I have been unable to use it to find the kind of "Black-Scholes-esque" expression I am looking for.

Comment: You can get the formula if you are willing to just define another special function as twice indefinite integral of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: maybe this should  be migrated to quantitative finance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the positive constant case
$$
\max(X-V,Y) = Y + \max(X-V-Y,0)
$$
so it's immediate.

In the other cases, you integrate the formula for constant $Y$ over the density of $Y.$

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit more you will get the check.